# How to put any app in a resizable (freeform, pop-up) window when it starts, from MacroDroid automation macro?

Tags: applications, automation, intents, macrodroid

I want to find how to do the question title.

- Any app (and Android launcher apps, to view my home screen shortcuts, on top of all apps).
- MacroDroid can send activity intent commands to Android.

I want to put an app in a resizable (freeform, pop-up) window *when a device action starts it*, in that automation app macro.

*Thank you for anything to help.*

---

***I can use [Taskbar](https://github.com/farmerbb/Taskbar).***